# Which .gitconfig file does Visual Studio use?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, version-control, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 15.2 (26430.15) Release, when I push a simple test edit of my cloned public Github repository, it fails; with an error message concerning an AggregateException, and an inability to spawn "askpass". Other SO posts relating to *that* issue don't work for me.

I'd like to try adding our http/https proxy settings manually to the .gitconfig file used by VS2017, but I can't find it. I have one already under cygwin, but I'm not sure if using that is a good idea - nor how to ask VS2017 to use it. (I also have Git Bash etc. already installed.)

Comment: One reason this can happen is when askpass is not able to read / write credentials. Could there be IT settings locking down your permissions? Here is a way to get more info:

1. Open command prompt
2. run `setx GIT_TRACE %TMP%\git.log`
3. run `setx GCM_TRACE %GIT_TRACE%`
4. Open Visual Studio, repro problem
5. open log, check for errors...
6. run `setx GIT_TRACE ""`
7. run `setx GCM_TRACE ""`


You can reach out to me at jamill AT Microsoft.com with the log, if you want.

Comment: Thanks jamill. Setting the proxy globally using the Git Bash prompt worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VS2017 has no Visual Studio specific `.gitconfig`.

You can alter the standard global git config file, or the local one for the repository in question.

To edit the global one:

```
git config --global --edit
```

To edit the repository local one

```
git config --edit
```

Comment: @user2023370 either should work. They do depend on an editor being configured, but that should be taken care of.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I applied the git config proxy command and after that VS could connect to the online repo.

Comment: This worked, alternatively you can go to the <localRepo>/.git/config file and add [http] httpVerify=false

Comment: Each Visual Studio 2017 installed on my machine has it's own Git.exe and it's own .gitconfig - and these might need updating if VS is not seeing changes to the .gitconfig in your user directory. I saw this when switching to schannel from SSH

Answer (score 11):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this issue, VS2017 and VS2019 **does** indeed use it's own instance of Git with it's own .gitconfig, at least if you're on the TFS platform.

These files are usually located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\etc

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\etc
```

If you want to check which path is searched when VS is looking for Git, go to:

`Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Package Management -> External Web Tools`

It's useful to know if you want to change which Git installation is being used.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct, however, more detail could be useful: VS 2017-2019 do not have a .gitconfig file, which is the global per user file. There IS however a lower precedence system-level gitconfig file (without the .) that's specific to the git installation. Since VS 2017-2019 have their own Git installation, you will find this within the VS folder hierarchy. If this file has configurations defined that don't match the default and are not redefined in higher precedence files, you can get unexpected results.

On the bright side, this is unlikely as VS Team Explorer settings don't expose this file and changing it via git config requires administrative access

Answer (score 0):

There just only one `.gitconfig` file for your local machine no matter you use VS, cygwin or git bash. And it’s usually located in the home directory. Such as if you are using windows OS, the `.gitconfig` file will located in `C:\users\uername`.

And all the global git config (`git confit --global`) settings are stored in the `.gitconfig` file. **If you need the http proxy setting is used for all git repositories**, you can set with `--global` option.

**If you just need the http proxy setting used for the current git repo** (local setting), you can set it without `--global` option. Then the setting will stored in `.git/config` file under the the current git repo directory.

Comment: This is not correct. I use portable git and I do not change system path. Based on need I set path to specific version of Git. VS code allows to specify external path for Git. VS does not and it uses its own internal Git. PATH variable is defined before internal Git and VS will find it when Git is on Path (your case). In my case it does not find it and and uses internal Git. Check path specified by scopperloit